# Minus is giving query block has incorrect number of result columns error in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, minus

I have a query where I want to `minus` lengths between 2 columns, so I executed the below query.

```html
SELECT RJ_FSA_ID as FSA_ID, ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000),4) AS NE_LENGTH, SPAN_REF_NAME,SPAN_NAME 
FROM NE.MV_SPAN@NE 
WHERE RJ_FSA_ID = 'GWLR0115' AND INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
AND SPAN_REF_NAME IN ('3x40-F-RG-ST-1L','3x40-F-RG-ST-1L','3x40-F-RG-ST-1L')
GROUP BY RJ_FSA_ID,SPAN_REF_NAME,SPAN_NAME
MINUS
SELECT AA.FSA_ID as FSA_ID, AA.MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH AS NE_LENGTH, BB.FSA_UG_ACTUAL FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS AA
INNER JOIN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS BB
ON AA.JOB_ID = BB.JOB_ID
WHERE AA.FSA_ID = 'GWLR0115';
```

SO while executing it I get error as

> ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns

Comment: [The UNION \[ALL\], INTERSECT, MINUS Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/The-UNION-ALL-INTERSECT-MINUS-Operators.html#GUID-B64FE747-586E-4513-945F-80CB197125EE): *The corresponding expressions in the select lists of the component queries of a compound query must match in number and must be in the same data type group (such as numeric or character).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MINUS` finds the results in the first result set that are not in the second result set; to do that it needs to compare the columns and see if they have identical values across the result sets.

The first query has 4 columns, the second query has 3 columns. The database is correct that you cannot `MINUS` one result set from another because they have different numbers of columns.

```sql
SELECT RJ_FSA_ID as FSA_ID,
       ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000),4) AS NE_LENGTH,
       SPAN_REF_NAME,
       SPAN_NAME 
FROM   NE.MV_SPAN@NE 
WHERE  <rest_of_query>
MINUS
SELECT AA.FSA_ID as FSA_ID,
       AA.MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH AS NE_LENGTH,
       BB.FSA_UG_ACTUAL
FROM   TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS AA
       INNER JOIN <rest_of_query>;
```

Either:

- Remove a column from the first query; or
- Add a column to the second query.

Comment: ok, with taking 2 columns in Select it's giving me error as `ORA-12704: character set mismatch
12704. 00000 -  "character set mismatch"`

Comment: Also with one column its displaying same value and it's not doing the minus part

Comment: @hud Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77824218/edit) and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; the queries you are using; the issues/errors you are getting with those queries; and the expected output for those queries. Just giving an error message is not constructive when we have no setup code to tell us why you might be getting that error and stating "it's not doing the minus part" is not constructive when we don't know what data you are putting in nor what you expect as the output.